# SEO asp.net description spelling order

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, seo

Hey guys my problem is really simple for know how to figure it out one , i use Page.Description method for SEO but  i need a little bit more.This is my code.

```
    public static string oletumdeger(string sorgu , string sutun,string vtbag,string duzen)
{
    string don = "";
    using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(vtbag))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sorgu, cnn))
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string deger = row[sutun].ToString();
                    don += string.Format(duzen);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return don;
}
```

i need acces "duzen" variable in my aspx page.
my page code.

```
<%Page.MetaDescription = elmurphy.oletumdeger
("select * from urun", "baslik", vtbag , ","+deger); %>
```

i hope i can explain it sorry about english it is low , yet :/

Comment: 1 more question not importent that much my database connection , it need anything else like dispose or close ?

Comment: But you are not changing `duzen` in `oletumdeger`, so why you can't just use `","+deger`?

Comment: i want a general method for myself and any one to use this method